# How to avoid Implicit Type Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use **STRING_AGG** function in a INT column. And getting a implicit type conversion warning. I think its affecting my query performance. How can I avoid this?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
     STRING_AGG(ES.SomeIntID, '#') AS Something
     FROM SomeTable 
     GROUP BY OtherID
```

I have tried to convert/cast the *SomeIntID* value explicitly to INT and NVARCHAR(12) but no improvement.

The warning:

> convert_issue: Cardinality Estimate
> expression: CONVERT(nvarchar(12), SomeIntID, 0)

It's significant as this function is being used multiple times in the query. I think this conversion is increasing my WorkFile/WorkTable logical read too.

Attempted query to convert:

```
STRING_AGG(CAST(ES.SomeIntID as nvarchar(12)), N'#') AS Something
```

AND

```
STRING_AGG(CAST(ES.SomeIntID as varchar(12)), '#') AS Something
```

Comment: please show the query that you have tried to use with the convert function

Comment: Updated the question. @pinakeep

Comment: what is you sql server version used? and how many  row table you need use?

Comment: SQL server 2017. @Amirhossein

Answer (score 3):

I think you can safely ignore that warning on the query plan:

> Type conversion in expression
> (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(12),[t].[task_id],0)) may affect
> "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice

Please look at [this query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkJu4cha8)

If cardinality estimate was affected by the conversion, then estimated number of rows would be significantly different than actual number of rows, but they are equals in this case.

Please, look at estimated and actual number of rows differences to find out if cardinality estimate might be affected.

Also replace `STRING_AGG(ES.SomeIntID, '#') AS Something`with `SUM(ES.SomeIntId) AS AnythingElse` to see if query plans are different and there are different cardinality estimates.

Comment: Estimated and actual row numbers are equal. I am not familiar with cardinality number right now, I'll read about it.

As for the check with the SUM function, both of the queries does index scan. The only difference is in the sort, as its not needed in the SUM. @Jesus

Comment: @nightElf91, then you can safely ignore the warning.